# Unexpected response output when creating an S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

so I have this python code to create an s3 bucket:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def create_bucket(bucket, secret):
    s3 = boto3.Session(
        region_name="my-region-1",
        aws_access_key_id=secret["aws_access_key_id"],
        aws_secret_access_key=secret["aws_secret_access_key"]
    )

    try:
        response = s3.create_bucket(
            ACL="private",
            Bucket=bucket,
            CreateBucketConfiguration={
                'LocationConstraint': 'my-region-1'
            }
        )
    except ClientError:
        return None

    return response["Location"]

print(create_bucket("bucketname", secret))
```

which creates the bucket in `my-region-1` as it should, but what I get as output is `/bucketname` instead of bucket URL (`http://bucketname.s3.my.domain.name`). [This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/create_bucket.html) manual implies that my code is correct (down at the examples section there's my use-case exactly), the URL should be printed if I provide `'LocationConstraint': 'my-region-1'`, yet I get the result of the other example (the one without providing LocationConstraint).

Anything I am missing?

Comment: You are creating a bucket in `us-east-1`?

Comment: Yes,  _in the example_ location is an URL, but documentation states location is `A forward slash followed by the name of the bucket`.  Also there is no mentions of URL in the response in AWS API documentation. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html

Comment: The code that you posted does not work: 1. Session object does not have create_bucket method. You're missing s3 client creation.  2. print cannot work as you're sending `secret` that does is not previously defined

Comment: @jellycsc no, it's a customized AZ. We recently changed the AZ name but I can confirm that the previous customized AZ name had the URL string as a return value. Could it be because we switched to StorageGrid?

Comment: @Caldazar this isn't the exact code, I only pasted the relevant stuff. The session object works just fine and the bucket is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some experimenting and found that the examples are accurate, but one piece of information is missing.

**First example**

```py
response = client.create_bucket(
    Bucket='examplebucket',
    CreateBucketConfiguration={
        'LocationConstraint': 'eu-west-1',
    },
)

print(response)
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
    'Location': 'http://examplebucket.s3.amazonaws.com/',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

This works as shown in the documentation. The `LocationConstraint` specifies the **Region** where the bucket should be created. It returns the `Location` as a URL (as shown above).

**Second example**

```py
response = client.create_bucket(
    Bucket='examplebucket',
)

print(response)
```

Expected Output:

```json
{
    'Location': '/examplebucket',
    'ResponseMetadata': {
        '...': '...',
    },
}
```

This example **only works for the `us-east-1` region**. It seems to be backwards-compatible with the 'original' S3 (before there were multiple regions). The `Location` is returned as a slash followed by the bucket name. The code **fails for other regions**, stating:

> The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.

Comment: Thanks for the research. We don't use us-east-1 and I didn't experience any failure message with and without `LocationConstraint`, in both cases it gives back `/bucketname`.

We switched to a StorageGrid bucket endpoint, could it be the reason?

Comment: Oh, you're using an **S3-Compatible endpoint** (not actual Amazon S3)? You should have mentioned this in your question. The behaviour is totally up to how that company implemented their system.

Comment: I see. OK, I'll adjust then. Thank you!